# Oracle - check if record with same conditions exists with later timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find records in our companies Oracle Database, which represent revision interventions for a specific procedure (icpm code).
So I have to check if patients/cases got the same procedure twice during their stay in hospital (partitioning by casenumber, cause that represents one stay).

My idea was to use `EXISTS` to check if a later record with the same procedure code but later date exists, but somehow this query still gives me all the records, also those with just one operation/intervention at all. I can't seem to figure out my error.

Any idea on what is going wrong here? Thanks for any helpful advice!

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        f.FALLNR AS "Casenumber",
        f.FALLID AS "CaseID",
        TO_CHAR(f.AUFNDAT, 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS "Admission",
        TO_CHAR(f.ENTLDAT, 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS "Dischrage",
        CONCAT(CONCAT(np.VORNAME, ' '), np.NAME) AS "Name",
        icpm.ICPM AS "OPS",
        --LISTAGG(DISTINCT ei.KURZBEZ, ', ') OVER (PARTITION BY f.FALLNR) AS "Eingriffe",
        LISTAGG(DISTINCT TO_CHAR(op.OP_DATUM, 'DD.MM.YYYY'), ', ') OVER (PARTITION BY f.FALLNR) AS "Dates of interventions",
        FIRST_VALUE(TO_CHAR(op.OP_DATUM, 'DD.MM.YYYY')) OVER (PARTITION BY f.FALLNR ORDER BY op.OP_DATUM ASC) AS "First intervention",
        oe.OEBENEKURZ AS "Department"
    FROM 
        FALL f
        INNER JOIN NATPERSON np ON np.PERSNR = f.PERSNR 
        INNER JOIN OP op ON op.FALLID = f.FALLID
        INNER JOIN FALL_ICPM fi ON fi.FALLID = f.FALLID
        INNER JOIN ICPM icpm ON icpm.ICPMID = fi.ICPMID 
        INNER JOIN ORGAEBENE oe ON oe.OEBENEID = fi.OEBENEID
        INNER JOIN PROTOKOLLE pr ON pr.OP_ID = op.OP_ID
        INNER JOIN OS_MUP.OP_EINGRIFFE ope ON ope.PROTID = pr.PROTID 
        INNER JOIN OS_MUP.EINGRIFFE ei ON ei.EINGRID = ope.EINGRID 
    WHERE
        (f.STORNO_DATUM IS NULL AND fi.STORNO_DATUM IS NULL)
        AND icpm.ICPM = '5-987.0'
        AND (op.STORNO_DATUM IS NULL AND op.REFUSAL_DATE IS NULL)
        AND fi.OEBENEID = 10081
    ) t1
WHERE 
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM 
                FALL f1
                INNER JOIN FALL_ICPM fi2 ON fi2.FALLID = f1.FALLID
                INNER JOIN ICPM icpm1 ON icpm1.ICPMID = fi2.ICPMID 
                INNER JOIN OP op2 ON op2.FALLID = f1.FALLID
            WHERE
                f1.FALLID = t1."CaseID"
                AND op2.OP_DATUM > TO_DATE(t1."First intervention")
                AND icpm1.ICPM = t1."OPS"
                AND fi2.OEBENEID = 10081
                AND (op2.STORNO_DATUM IS NULL AND op2.REFUSAL_DATE IS NULL)
            )
```

Comment: Please, provide [**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It doesn't matter what the joins you execute because the question is about finding some records in *some* dataset regardless of how it was generated

Comment: `TO_DATE(t1."First intervention")` with no format mask looks suspicious; the behaviour will depend on your session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting. And does `OP_DATUM` have non-midnight times? At best you're converting a date to a string and back to the correct date but even then you are losing any time components along the way; so if the first intervention is say 2021-08-04 09:00:00 then that will be included in your exists clause, as it is after 2021-08-04 00:00:00. I would move all the date formatting to the outer query to avoid confusion.